# Why is colder seawater more compressible?

Tags: oceanography

I know compressibility is related to the pressure and temperature of the water parcel... but what is the physical/molecular reason why colder water is more compressible?

Comment: I expected hot water to be more compressible than cold water. Lets wait for the answer.

Comment: At least for seawater it can be computed fairly easily that colder water is more compressible... But just because I can make a computation and observe that cold water is more compressible doesn't mean I understand the physical principles behind it!

Comment: As like liquid is more compressible than solid, hot water is more likely to get compressed than cold water. Thant's what I think.

Answer (score -1):

Cold water is slightly more compressible than hot water (assuming that both these water parcels have appropriate salinities to make them equal densities) at the same pressure because the molecules in hot water have a higher kinetic energy. Thus pressure will need to do more work to compress hotter water as it doesn't want to be held together. Colder water on the other hand is less energetic and molecules are more willing to be pushed together.

Comment: How would anything of what you write be different for ideal gas? More energetic particles will resist more even there. But that by itself does not mean different compressibility $-\frac{p}{V}\frac{dV}{dp}$. Ideal gas compressibility, for example, does not depend on temperature or pressure.